# error with ssis package in sql server job

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Я сделал пакет служб SSIS, который экспортирует данные из Microsoft SQL Server и импортирует их в файлы .csv и mysql. Я использую *прокси-аккаунт*, и он работает (без него нет), но только когда *пользователь вошел в систему*. **Как заставить его работать, когда пользователь вышел из системы!?** Заранее спасибо.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Во-первых, сменил пользовательский DSN на системный.
[источник](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14401/How-to-Schedule-and-Run-a-SSIS-package-DTS-Job-in)

> Does any connection manager in the package use ODBC DSN? If any ODBC
>   DSN is used, please make sure the DSN type is System DSN rather than
>   User DSN. The user DSN may not be accessible when the user that create
>   the DSN logs off.

Затем, создал новый proxy и дал ему другие права.
[источник](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cbf9942c-7a1d-4c20-84d5-9326e1ae0933/ssis-package-only-runs-when-user-is-logged?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

```
Use master
CREATE CREDENTIAL [MyCredential] WITH IDENTITY = 'yourdomain\myWindowAccount', secret = 'WindowLoginPassword'
Use msdb
Sp_add_proxy @proxy_name='MyProxy', @credential_name='MyCredential'
Sp_grant_login_to_proxy @login_name=' devlogin', @proxy_name='MyProxy'
Sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name='MyProxy', @subsystem_name='SSIS'
```